# Magento quote items modify sku

Tags: magento

I need to change SKU on quoteitems and I do it like this:

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $item->setSku($newSku);
    $item->save();
}
```

But magento always resets SKUs into their original values. Is there some easy way to change it, like superMode on prices? Or if not, then where can I find methods to rewrite, so that they ignore my custom SKUs?
Tried looking for it, but even if I remove cart init and save from index action, they still reset somewhere.

I need it to work in Magento 1.7-1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I didnt feel like waiting and found it.

You can find it in **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item** and there in function **setProduct**. This function is run every time the cart is shown and it resets the data from Product to Item.

Not sure if now my data will get through whole checkout process, will update the answer if not.

**EDIT**

This has solved only cart, will need to find also function for order. Will update when I get it.

**EDIT**

In the end, I don't advise you to do this. But if you need it then, the way to do it is to create observe on event sales_order_save_after and modify sku of order items. This seems to work everywhere, only in email after checkout it doesn't work, there you have to modify email. Also I use this only on configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing on my project using sales_quote_collect_totals_after

Just change quote item SKU as you want using this event.